# What is the actual meaning of "script" in php?

Tags: php

I know that php is a scripting language. But some of php codes/docs, like when i tried to use magic methods, still use the "script" word. Like the `__invoke()` method that is called when "a script tries to call an object as a function". Here, in "script tries" - what exactly does "script" here refer to?

Comment: I think in this context, script is just the name of the file you are running.

Comment: A program written in PHP, or any other scripting language, is called a script.

Comment: Generally, we refer to _scripting language_ to define code that don't require an explicit compilation. PHP is one of the languages that don't require explicit compilation. So, each php file you write is called _script_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *script* is a pretty vague term, generally, a script is a group of code that preforms in and around a root goal, like a script to generate a json file that has some input parameters which slightly modify the final output.

In PHP, you might have one main script in your project, or you may have many fragments - there is not hard line that says *what is a script*.

You may even call other scripts from yours; voting to close as opinion based.